# Identify unused endpoints in dotnet core api on azure webapp

Tags: .net-core, azure-web-app-service

I am working on an project that consists of multiple micro services api projects.

The api projects were carved out of a single Monolith solution. Unfortunately how it "carving" was done resulted in copy pasted endpoints in multiple repos solutions. Below is an oversimplified example of how this was done

```
before

monolith/account/
monolith/payment/
monolith/order/

micro service : account
monolith/account/ [used]
monolith/payment/ [copy pasted unused]
monolith/order/   [copy pasted unused]

micro service : payment
monolith/account/ [copy pasted unused]
monolith/payment/ [used]
monolith/order/   [copy pasted unused]

micro service : order
monolith/account/ [copy pasted unused]
monolith/payment/ [copy pasted unused]
monolith/order/   [used]
```

How can programmatically figure out unused endpoints for each repo ?

- We have the apis deployed on azure web apps
- We use application insights on all of the apps

Answer (score 0):

App service HTTP logs can be used to find how many requests are made to each endpoint on each app service.

You can do it by going to the **app service → Logs → New Query** on the Azure portal and running a query like this:

```
AppServiceHTTPLogs 
| where CsUriStem == '/monolith/account/' or CsUriStem == '/monolith/payment/' or CsUriStem == '/monolith/order/'
| summarize count() by CsUriStem
```

It will return a table with the number of requests for each endpoint so you should be able to find those that are not being used.